# Marketing Cloud SOAP API send Email to List

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, soap-api, list

I'm attempting to make a SOAP API call to have email sent to a new list every day. The HTML Email is created in Content Builder and works from the UI. The List creation, Subscriber creation(on the list) is all good with SOAP API calls. Does anyone have working sample SOAP code of how to send that email to the list?

I think the solution is to Create an Email Send Definition (hooking the email to the list) and then to Start that Email Send Definition. The Sample code on the SF site usually doesn't work (If it validates against the WSDL, It doesn't work, bad validated XML will work, like they are using a different WSDL in the service that is published). I have the Sample SOAP from: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_an_email_send_definition_using_the_web_service_api.htm?search_text=email%20definition.

This leaves me with more questions about what the CustomerKey is since it has 3 different values for various objects and I have not idea what the SendDefinitionList is... The documentation concerning what the IDs and Keys are in Objects, just says things like "System-controlled, read-only text string identifier for object.". Not sure why I have to specify something that is read only in a create request.

Comment: My solution was to create and EmailSendDefinition. Then I had to do a Retrieve of the EmailSendDefinition to get the ID (Create only returns ObjectID). Then I could do a Start of the EmailSendDefinition. Because the Update of the EmailSendDefinition would not work (no examples, trial and error was all error) I have to delete the EmailSendDefinition using the Delete API and then recreate with new list the next day.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. The email name was duplicated in classic and Content Builder. I was able to use SOAP to send the email to a list, but just discovered it sent the classic email. When I attempted to do same for mail only in Content Builder, no luck. Solution is to attempt using REST.